# Bootstrap 4 100vh container within auto-width column is overflowing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly new to bootstrap. I have a bootstrap 4 page with three columns. The middle column has a container where I've arranged 4 images in a grid. On large screens, I want this container to be as large as possible while still fitting in the screen (and preserving the aspect ratio of the images inside. I can accomplish something like this through trial and error by manually setting the column width (e.g. col-lg-5), but depending on the aspect ratio of the screen, the image container either does not fill the entire height, or overflows beyond the view. Allowing the column to be auto-width results in the column occupying 100% width (the images are large) which is not what I want. I was able to set the height of the image container to 100% using `max-height: 100vh;`, and I thought this should do the trick, but the rows inside that container don't scale to fit. Instead, there is overflow in the vertical direction.

Here is the example:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto" style="background-color:red;">
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- I want the content in this column to take up 100% height on large screens, but 100% width on small screens (columns stack) -->
        <div class="col-auto" style="background-color:green;">
            <h2>Column 2</h2>
            <div id="img-container" class="container" style="max-height:100vh;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" style="background-color:blue;">
            <h2>Column 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/x1EiL25vhm

Current:
[image]
Currently, the images are overflowing the container and I can't figure out how to get them to scale properly.

Desired outcome:
[image]
I would like the image container to always occupy 100% height with automatic width, until all available space is used on the sides. On small screens the three columns should stack vertically and column 2 will occupy 100% width.

Comment: Could you share your code with us ? It would help to see what's not working out :)

Comment: Please don't use an external site to show your code, as it's not guaranteed to be static and not always accessible by all readers. Instead, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code you're having issues with using [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: `style="max-height:100%;"`

Comment: I edited it to include the code here. Does the link not work?

Comment: max-height 100% does not work - there is no overflow in that case, but the container is not scaling to the height of the view

Comment: Are you after is fit-to-the-current-window right ? col-auto will cause you some issues in that case. use col-<media_size>-x https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @SupunDeSilva I want those images to occupy as much space as they can without needing to scroll down the page to see all four. As I tried to explain, col-<media_size>-x is not a great solution because the images could be too small (white space between bottom of images and window) or too large (need to scroll down) depending on the aspect ratio of the window. Not all large or xl screens are created equal, as I've realized by trying that.

Comment: @KarlSchneider My concern was the smaller view ports. It renders weirdly on small windows.

How many images would you be fitting in to the middle view port ?

`Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.`

It causes overflow because it tries to retain the aspect ration once the width is decided.

Comment: Added an answer, check it out

Answer (score 0):

**A sorta hack that MAY work**

1. **Smaller screen sizes need to be though through**
2. The reason why it will not expand after a certain width is that the inner `<div id="img-container" class="container">`  making it `<div id="img-container" class="container-fluid">` will expand more
3. Reason for `max-height:46vh` is to allow room for the **Column 2** header. Maybe it is better to calc on the fly

**Code**

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="container-fluid"  style="max-height:100vh;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto" style="background-color:red;">
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- I want the content in this column to take up 100% height on large screens, but 100% width on small screens (columns stack) -->
        <div class="col-auto" style="background-color:green;" >
            <h2 class="header-2">Column 2</h2>
            <div id="img-container" class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png" style="max-height:46vh;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png" style="max-height:46vh;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png" style="max-height:46vh;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col p-0">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://climate.met.psu.edu/ewall/test.png" style="max-height:46vh;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" style="background-color:blue;">
            <h2>Column 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working to keep the images in check, but now I have a problem with column widths. On tall but narrower screens, there is column wrapping (or a scrollbar, if I set flex-nowrap). How do I get all three to fit in the window without explicitly specifying widths? Ideally I'd like column 1 to be sized so that there's no text wrapping of the heading, set column 3 to a fixed min-width, and have column 2 occupy the rest of the space.

Comment: :D, this is what I meant in point #1.
I'll see what I can do. May be 6-7 H time